# how to import IntelliJ Idea Android Project To codename one

Tags: intellij-idea, codenameone, intellij-plugin

1. Can I Import Android Project Java Language In codename one at IntelliJ Idea?
2. is there many differences between IntelliJ Idea and codename one Project Developing(what about Codes And UI/UX Design)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No.
2. Yes.

Codename One is its own platform on top of the IDE so you would need to adapt your code to match Codename One API's rather than Android API's.

The UI designer is a custom UI designer and not the one builtin to Codename One since its designed for mobile.